Error when tryng to import quantum aer noise
I have been trying to implement noise reducer in aer simulator in my code. This is the line of code for import:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import NoiseModel
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise.errors import depolarizing_error

But the result show:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.providers.aer'


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use the qiskit_aer package, which you already seem to have given that the previous line don't raise any error:
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
from qiskit_aer.noise.errors import depolarizing_error

